Is it possible to call a method of a parent nested class on another object in C++?
Basically I have a class Argument and in it a union of all different data types:
union DefaultValues
{
public:
    bool mbDefault;
    char mchDefault;
    long long mllDefault;
    double mdDefault;
    QString msDefault;
} mvDefaultValues;

I also have a bunch of constructors for each data type, a destructor, and overloaded operators for each data type but ran into "Ambiguous method" errors.  So I tried to create An Argument constructor with a DefaultValues argument and it said there was no Copy constructor so I tried to create copy constructor but I need to call Argument::getDataType() to determine the datatype to determine what field to copy over.  Here's the copy constructor as I have it now:
DefaultValues(const DefaultValues &refCopy)
{
    if(refCopy.Argument::getDataType() == "bool")
        mbDefault = refCopy.mbDefault;
     else ...
}

Any ideas how to do this properly?  I'm currently using C++17.

What is Argument?

Side note, never use (untagged) unions in C++, they are an UB minefield. It is safer to use std::variant instead. See C++ core guidelines P.4, and read the section on unions

In some languages, when you define a class inside another class, the inner class "extends" the outer class (the inner class contains an instance of or inherits from the outer class). That doesn't happen in C++. If you define DefaultValues inside a Argument class, DefaultValues does not have any of the members of a Argument.

I know but isn't there a way to reference the parent class?  I know there is for the same class - like for the same instance, I could say in a method
Argument::getDefaultValue() 

and it wouldn't complain one bit - My issue is that I'm trying to do that on another instance (refCopy).

isn't there a way to reference the parent class? Yes, there is a way.  You add a parent pointer to the nested class, and construct that nested class with a pointer to its parent class instance.

Won't that take up memory in the union?  How can I have that as a 2nd data component of the union though?

To put the comment by François more clearly: There does not have to be an Argument associated with a DefaultValues, so it makes no sense to ask whether the language provides a way to get the former from the latter. For your last comment, just use a struct.

And to put it another way: Nested classes are just namespaces for the class names, not structural containment. You can have an Argument::DefaultValues object that isn't contained in an Argument wrapper object.

Weijun, Unfortunately there does as Argument has the getDataType method - Basically I'm creating a GUI program to automate/construct the C++ code for classes - It annoys me to type all that scaffolding (overloaded =, ==, !=, copy/move constructors, etc.) and code them - and an argument is well an argument - as I use default arguments, it'll be necessary - I ended up just deleting the union and going with a straight "QString" as it's going to be composed into a string anyway and output to a file so I figured why confuse the issue - but I still want to know how to do this if possible.

Is there a reason you are not using a std::variant? It is supposed to replace almost all uses of unions, except for really low-level codes, and provides many of the "scaffoldings" you mentioned.

@SethD.Fulmer I think you are misunderstanding the point being made. Basically you have class A { union B { ... }; ... }; In this situation there is no relationship between A and B. It is not possible (in C++) to get from A to B or from B to A. The fact that one class is declared inside another does not make a relationship between them. So the short answer is, no it is not possible. Given the way C++ is designed the question does not really make any sense.

Then I guess I will just stick with deleting the union and going with a flat string like I did.  I have really never used unions - even when I coded in C - I found them useless but I saw the possible use with this application.  Thanks everyone.  Appreciated!

Weijun - No I have no idea how to use std::variant or I would have possibly considered it - I haven't really used much of the STL because I don't like the methods that are involved in them - like with list/vector - push_back makes no sense - Add/append makes a LOT more sense to me - and std::string - there's no easy way to get an all upper case version of a string - you have to use the std::algorithm library to do it and I keep having to look up the syntax for that so I prefer since I'm working in QT QString, QList, QMap, etc. over std::string, std::list/vector, std::map.

There is also a QT QVariant, but it's closer to std::any than it is to std::variant.

@SethD.Fulmer QT vs std:: is a matter of taste, personally I don't like QT's copy-on-write everywhere. Anyway, avoid unions if you may, they are a barely usable leftover from C (unless you really know what you want to achieve), any tagged union (be it std::variant, QVariant or boost::variant) will just do better.

I don't know what "Copy on Write" means honestly.  I don't like the lack of functionality in the STL - I actually created my own String class (er. Library) because I hate the STL.  I created my own List and Map as well.  I figured why do that if there is one I like there like in QT and the sizeof of the class was so big so it didn't make it too worth it.  I actually created my own Observer/Observable classes because I loved them in Java (version 8 or earlier).  In Java v9+, I created my own version as well too but I've done that so many times, I can code it in my sleep.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/implicit-sharing.html . I don't think the dislike for standard library (btw, STL is the name of a very old library, see stl) containers is reason enough not to use std::variant, as you can use std::variant independent of any standard library containers, but maybe I cannot convince you of that. Maybe your dislike extends to the whole standard library, I cannot know. Anyway, avoid bare unions at all costs as commented by alagner.

It's not due to dislike - it's due to ignorance - I have NO clue how to use it so I don't use it - Just like I don't know how to perform brain surgery so I don't try it :-P  I do know though that > 50% the STL classes lack very important features such as contains, indexOf, toUpper, toLower, trim, just to name a few - maybe they've added them in later versions of C++ but I know them from C++11 & currently am on C++17 - I doubt I'll ever try std::string or the collections as I hate having to implement all that functionality on my own.  I need it inherent with the classes like it in QT, VB, etc.

I found other ways to do the problem I'm trying to solve - since it wll all go to a file as a concatenation of a string, I send the value as a string and let the end compiler worry about data type when the program produced is compiled.
